# Android: Shoot on Google Map with SnapshotReadyCallback

Tags: android, google-maps

I have a problem with `SnapshotReadyCallback` to take a screenshoot of my `GoogleMap` view.

On my Nexus 5x I haven't any problem. I can take the shoot of `GoogleMap` view. But in Nexus 5, when I captured the image I can only see the Google logo but not any map. (In this case I used `SnapshotReadyCallback` from `GoogleMap` Android API)

I also tried to take a shoot from view (`Framelayout` that contain the map), same thing.

Why this happens?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

To use [SnapshotReadyCallback](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.SnapshotReadyCallback). First you need to import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.SnapshotReadyCallback in the activity.

here is some [example code](http://vaishalibhujbal.com/blogspot/?p=42).

Comment: Thank you for your time. But I said that I can on my device (5X). This presume that the import is fine. Or not? ;)